# Can you create a parameter query that allows you to select the field?

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to make a small database in Access that will have a button that allows you to type in a field name then set a high and low value, then it will display the values of that field in that range. I know how to set up the parameter query for the limits, but I do not know how make it prompt the user for a field. If there is a way I can have a drop down box for the field then click a button and set the limits, that would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you create a parameter query that allows you to select the field?

Not directly.

Your parameter value will most likely be a string which matches the name of a field in your table.  So you need to reference the value of the field whose name matches the parameter string.

You could use a `Switch` expression to map between them, but it can get ugly fast.

```sql
PARAMETERS Field_Name Text ( 255 ), lo_end IEEESingle, hi_end IEEESingle;
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE
    Switch
        (
            [Field_Name] = 'Field1', [Field1],
            [Field_Name] = 'Field2', [Field2],
            [Field_Name] = 'Field3', [Field3]
        )
    BETWEEN [lo_end] AND [hi_end];
```

Furthermore you may need to contend with misspelled field names and non-numeric field types (which aren't compatible with your value range constraint).

So although what you asked is possible, if it were me, I would look for a different approach.

Comment: I figured the name being a string would be a problem. I will probably just have a separate query for each of the fields. Thanks for your feedback!